# How to match string from list with text and do something

Tags: python

I have list of keywords let's say 6 in a list like this...

```
keywords = ['python', 'c plus plus', 'java', 'javascript', 'c#', 'assembly']
```

and have thousands of sentence like this...

```
 sentence = [
'my first python program was a scraping script',
'i want to learn c plus plus in future',
'i want to learn java in future too',
'i love javascript very much',
'my friend very knowledgeble in c# programming',
'i heard of assembly but never tried yet'
]
```

What i want to do is take a keyword from the keyword list let's say 'python' then search all sentence, if found then do something or else pass. I have tried something but if i add more keywords then code will be very long. I have search on SO but could not get what i want to accomplish. Is there a better way to it...thanks in advance.

Here is some code i have tried

```
keywords = ['python', 'c plus plus', 'java', 'javascript', 'c#', 'assembly']

sentence = [
'my first python program was a scraping script',
'i want to learn c plus plus in future',
'i want to learn java in future too',
'i love javascript very much',
'my friend very knowledgeble in c# programming',
'i heard of assembly but never tried yet'
]

for i in sentence:
    if 'python' in i:
        lang = 'python'
        begining = i.split('python')[-1]
        ending = i.split('python')[0]
    elif 'c plus plus' in i:
        lang = 'c plus plus'
        begining = i.split('c plus plus')[-1]
        ending = i.split('c plus plus')[0]
    elif 'java' in i:
        lang = 'java'
        begining = i.split('java')[-1]
        ending = i.split('java')[0]
    elif 'javascript' in i:
        lang = 'javascript'
        begining = i.split('javascript')[-1]
        ending = i.split('javascript')[0]
    elif 'c#' in i:
        lang = 'c#'
        begining = i.split('c#')[-1]
        ending = i.split('c#')[0]
    elif 'assembly' in i:
        lang = 'assembly'
        begining = i.split('assembly')[-1]
        ending = i.split('assembly')[0] 
    else:
        pass
    print lang, begining, ending
```

Comment: You just want to loop through both lists. `for word in keywords: for sentence in sentences: if word in sentence: do stuff`

Comment: *"...but if i add more keywords then code will be very long. "* Sure thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate more efficiently as in the following:"

```
for kw in keywords:
    for sent in sentences:
        if kw in sent:
             lang = kw
             beginning,ending = sent.split(kw,1) ## Force to only split 1 time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
languages = [...]
sentences = [...]

for sentence in sentences:
    for language in languages:
        if language in sentence:
            ...
```